# Hosting a file system in production?

Tags: node.js, file-systems

Sorry if this is broad. But I'm confused on how to scale a file system.

I'm currently working on the server side of a webapp with Node(Express)js, its file system module, and mongoDB.

I'm storing images locally right now but don't understand where these would be stored in production. Are there dedicated cloud file servers that i could point to? Would whatever hosting platform i choose provide there own storage?

Or is storing the image in mongoDB my best bet over a file system?

Here's the code that's storing images locally in the project currently

```
const storageEngine = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: 'mylocalproject/data/images',
    filename(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.fieldname + '-' + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
})
const upload = multer({
    storage: storageEngine,
    limits: { fileSize:20000000 }//,
    // fileFilter: function(req, file, callback){
    //     validateFile(file, callback);
    // }
}).single('');

router.post('/uploadphoto', isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {

    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            return res.json(req.file);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: A hosting platform would provide a certain amount of local storage (local to your server) and will typically let you pay for more if you need more.  If you were hosting a ton of images and they just need to be downloadable by a browser and don't need to be on your server, you could also use a separate hosting service for your images (for example, the Smugmug photo service hosts their images on AWS).

Answer (score 0):

I would delay and defer this decision by designing an API for your system to request images be persisted through. Hang a plugin off of that that knows how to work with whatever you decide to use. That can be a local filesystem, ftp server, database, cloud, or whatever. Keep as much of your code as you can from knowing which you do.

Answer (score -1):

You should use cloud object storage for files. S3 or Google buckets and such.